# Vue - dynamically registered models?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

Inside a `Vue-component`, I'm making a list, but the number of entries in the list varies.

So it could be like **this**:

```
<form>
<input type="number" value="15" />
<input type="number" value="10" />
<input type="number" value="5" />

<input name="total" :value="summedTotal" /> <!-- (calculated dynamically) -->
</form>
```

Or like **this**:

```
<form>
<input type="number" value="15" />
<input type="number" value="10" />
<input type="number" value="5" />
<input type="number" value="17" />
<input type="number" value="20" />

<input name="total" :value="summedTotal" /> <!-- (calculated dynamically) -->
</form>
```

If I had a fixed set of input fields, then I would have solved it using `v-model`. But now the number of 'models' are dynamic.

Can I somehow still use `v-model` to solve this?

---

Currently I'm adding an `@keypress`-event, finding the input ( `document.getElementById( '....' )` and finding the value from that. But I need to set a delay for it to work. I could use `keyup` or some other event-watcher, but it all becomes really hacky, really quick.

The actual code is (an advanced version of) **this**:

```
<form>
<input 
   type="number" 
   v-for="(entry, index) in list" 
   name="entry.id" 
   value="entry.initial_value"
   :id="'entry-id__' + entry.id" @keypress="calculateSum()" 
/>

<input name="total" :value="summedTotal" /> <!-- (calculated dynamically) -->
</form>
```

Comment: On what is it depending how many `<input>`s you'll have? Do you have an array of objects which is dynamic? Usually you would loop through this array and generate the `<input>`s like this. If you have specific logic on each `<input>` it's better to move it to its own component, where you can define the whole logic for one instance instead of looping through all the elements on each interaction. And do not use `document.getElementById()`. An `id` must be unique for the whole page and therefore you cannot reuse the component on the same page. Use `refs` instead (`<input ref="">` and `this.$refs`)

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to use a `v-model` that will allow your input fields to change the value in the list :

```
<input 
   type="number" 
   v-for="(entry, index) in list"
   :key="'input-field-'+entry.id"
   name="entry.id" 
   v-model="entry.initial_value"
   :id="'entry-id__' + entry.id" 
/>
```

When a new value is set by the user, it should modify this precise value in your `list` object.

Then keep your last line as is:

```
<input name="total" :value="summedTotal" />
```

with `summedTotal` being a `computed` value summing the values of your list.

If you don't want to change your original list, you can make a deep copy first and then use `copiedList` for your v-model:

```
data {
  copiedList : JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(this.list))
}
```

Here is a Snippet that works:

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    list: [{
        id: 1,
        initial_value: 3
      },
      {
        id: 2,
        initial_value: 1
      },
      {
        id: 3,
        initial_value: 7
      },
      {
        id: 4,
        initial_value: 2
      },
    ]
  },
  computed: {
    summedValued() {
      return this.list.reduce((acc, c) => {
        return acc + parseInt(c.initial_value || 0);
      }, 0)
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <div v-for="(entry, index) in list" :key="'input-field-'+entry.id">
    ID {{entry.id}}: <input type="number" name="entry.id" v-model="entry.initial_value" :id="'entry-id__' + entry.id" />
  </div>
  TOTAL :{{summedValued}}

</div>
```